# Looking for a word that shows connection, perhaps medically

Tags: single-word-requests

Hope this is a proper site to post this type of question , apologies if not.
Having no luck remembering a word that describes one condition leading to another condition .
In a medical sense in my particular situation, but interested in any word that might work.
Used this word years ago, might begin with the letter c, but I am just not sure.
Thank you all for any assistance .
Peace and health

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: 'Contingent' or a synonym?

Comment: Is it Domino effect?

Comment: Had to switch devices,bandwidth problems... Dealing wth something along the lines of,  Due to a broken back,the patient developed agoraphobia and major mood disorder as a result. The depression was  ( need word here )  to the/with the broken back.  Hope that made sense, sorry...

Comment: Correlation? In the sense of "Correlation does not imply causation."

Comment: The depression was *consequential* to the back injury.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequela

**sequelae** (consequences) - It is different from, but is a consequence of, the first condition.

The phrase **status post**, abbreviated in writing as s/p, is used to discuss sequelae with reference to their cause.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sequela

usually sequelaeA condition which is the consequence of a previous disease or injury.

‘the long-term sequelae of infection’

Answer (score 1):

The word 'contingent' applies here; one thing (B) is contingent upon another (A) if it is necessary that A exists / occurs / is done for B to exist / occur / be done:

> **contingent** adjective ...
>
> 1: dependent on or conditioned by something else
>
> - *Payment is contingent on fulfillment of certain conditions.*
> - a plan contingent on the weather

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contingent)]

> - In patients undergoing curative surgical tumor resection for Cushing’s syndrome, the time to recovery of adrenal function is
>     contingent upon the underlying etiology of the disease, according to
>     recent findings.

[[Endocrine Today](https://www.healio.com/endocrinology/adrenal/news/online/%7B9d0d5a2c-af03-4b5e-aaa3-1d18bcbfda12%7D/cushings-syndrome-subtype-affects-postoperative-time-to-adrenal-recovery)]

[but note that 'contingent' has other sub-senses]

Answer (score 1):

[Comorbidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comorbidity).

> In medicine, comorbidity is the presence of one or more additional
>   conditions co-occurring with (that is, concomitant or concurrent with)
>   a primary condition; in the countable sense of the term, a comorbidity
>   (plural comorbidities) is each additional condition.

A newer sense of the word - the secondary condition may be caused by the primary:

> (2) to indicate a medical condition in a patient that causes, is caused
>   by, or is otherwise related to another condition

Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

How about **complication**? From M-W:

> **[complication](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complication)**: secondary disease or condition developing in the course of a primary disease or condition

A patient could have a series of **complications** -- **complications** on top of **complications** -- one bad thing leading to another.